# Flaky ECS Fargate deploys (An AppSpec file is required, but could not be found)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We have some flaky CodeDeploy errors that are frustrating. In about 10% of our deploys we get the following error : *An AppSpec file is required, but could not be found in the revision.*

The problem is that when we download the artifact zip file from s3 we clearly see a `appspec.yaml` file. Our build script doesn't change between deploys and when we rerun the pipeline on the same commit (using the "Release change" button), without changing anything, it works.

The error message isn't helpful and it seems like CodeDeploy isn't 100% reliable.

We use ECS Fargate using Blue/Green Deployment.

Our `buildspec.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  parameter-store:
    BUILD_ENV: key-foo-site-node-env

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
      - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-6)
      - ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account')
      - REPOSITORY_URI="$ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/foo-site"
      - echo Saving source version into version.txt...
      - echo $IMAGE_TAG >> version.txt
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the app Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI/app:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - echo Building the nginx Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI/nginx:$IMAGE_TAG docker/nginx
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`

      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI/app:$IMAGE_TAG
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI/nginx:$IMAGE_TAG

      # Create a valid json file that will be used to create a new task definition version
      # Using sed we need to replace $APP_IMAGE and $NGINX_IMAGE by image urls
      - echo Creating a task definition json
      - sed "s+\$APP_IMAGE+$REPOSITORY_URI/app:$IMAGE_TAG+g; s+\$NGINX_IMAGE+$REPOSITORY_URI/nginx:$IMAGE_TAG+g;" taskdef.$BUILD_ENV.json > register-task-definition.json

      # Using the aws cli we register a new task definition
      # We need to new task definition arn to create a valid appspec.yaml
      # If you need debugging, the next line is useful
      # - aws --debug ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json "$(cat register-task-definition.json)" > task-definition.json
      - echo Creating an appspec.yaml file
      - TASK_DEFINITION_ARN=`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json "$(cat register-task-definition.json)" --query 'taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn' --output text`
      - sed "s+\$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN+$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN+g" appspec.yml > appspec.yaml

artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yaml
    - register-task-definition.json
    - task-definition.json
```

Our `appspec.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "$TASK_DEFINITION_ARN"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "nginx"
          ContainerPort: "80"
```

Comment: Have you figured out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not relevant anymore, but it looks like your AppSpec file has a different suffix (`.yml`) than indicated in the `artifcats` definition of the buildspec file (`.yaml`).